# Hardware factory-reset for Philips TV (PFH5500)

Tags: factory-reset, android-tv

I'm trying to boot a Philips TV (model 48PFH5500/88) into recovery mode. The television is stuck in the Philips logo splash screen and is essentially bricked. The front LED is pulsing every 1 sec, which I've read is an indication of an issue.

#### Tried the following:

- Connecting to it via `adb` to boot into recovery - the device is not seen.
- Hardware reboot by holding the joystick in the back on the "down" position when plugging in the TV and keeping it there for several minutes.
- Unplugging for 1 to 10 minutes and re-connecting.
- Entering support codes via the remote (per support manual) to enter service default mode (SDM) or factory mode.

All of these did not yield any response.

I'm looking for a hardware based reset/factory-reset method. Is there any trick I could try to force the device to start anew?

Thanks.